# SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am having chart on my asp report and when I run it on visual studio this chart report works fine. But when I host it(loacal and server both) it's not display chart image on the report. When I get element URL it's like this,

http://MY_IP:90/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Mode=true&ReportID=952c531af6f24b31a305d2f640e4fa7d&ControlID=4bb8b3618ffd40f8af264c9a1103f91e&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=ReportImage&StreamID=C_3_S

Can some one please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution issue was for IIS7 I need to have more handler it's like this,

```
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
  <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
  <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
```

Last one was that I have missed.